# WordPress Scrolling Theme Shifting Left When Menu Links Are Clicked

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have an issue which I assume is CSS, but I cannot seem to find the fix for it.  I am using a WordPress theme (the site can be viewed here: http://sencb.com).  Everything functions as intended, unless the screen size is somewhere sub 1050px wide.  I know most modern monitors are much wider than that, but this is still a fix I'd like to find.  The problem, when the screen/browser window is smaller in width, usually somewhere around 1050px, the whole scrolling content side (the right side) shifts left over the fixed area and navigation menu.  I've tried just about everything I can think of, so I am in hopes someone here can find the fix.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the sidebar is using position fixed. Whatever the browser's width/height and scroll coordinates, the sidebar will always be in the same place in the window. The content area, on the other hand, moves naturally and is able to appear anywhere on the browser window space. Sometimes it just happens to overlap the sidebar.

Try adding `z-index: 300` to `#main-leftarea` and see if that works for you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.  Adding the z-index to the #main-leftarea keeps the left sibe bar on top, but the right content still shifts left and under the left sidebar.  I guess that's better than before since the menu is still visible, but is there any way to keep the right side from shifting at all?